# SFTP in PHP (phpseclib3\Net\SFTP) – filtering directory listing results server side possible?

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I'm trying to look for specific files on an SFTP server using PHP. The file listing is quite large, so I'm hoping to filter the results using wildcards rather than iterating through every file, if possible.

When I use either `psftp` or even the default Windows command line `sftp` command, I'm able to filter the results using something like `ls prefix_*.txt` or whatever, and the files returned are, as expected, filtered by the filemask I used.

However, phpseclib3\Net\SFTP does not seem to have an `ls` command, just `nlist` and `rawlist`. Both of which offer the option to do sorting, but don't seem to work with wildcards.

I also tried this, thinking perhaps the SSH command would work:
`$sftp->exec('ls');` but the server quits with *'This service allows sftp connections only.'*

So my question is whether that is possible in PHP, or I need to just accept that I'll have to loop through all of the returned files every time I want to filter them.  If that's the case, how does the `ls` command in those other tools work? Is the filtering handled locally in the `psftp` and Windows `sftp` applications (i.e. they still need to retrieve a full directory listing behind the scenes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filtering in `sftp` and `psftp` is done locally. In SFTP protocol, there's no API to do the filtering server-side.

The phpseclib does not have local-side filtering implemented. You indeed have to do it on your own.